# TextMate - Keep editor in focus when doing Run for Python scripts

Tags: python, ide, textmate

I'm writing Python and I find it annoying that when I press Cmd + R, TextMate (1.5.11) would focus on the "running..." window, so I have to switch back to the main window to continue writing code.

Is it possible to prevent TextMate from doing that and run my code in background — or, would you recommend an alternative way (another bundle?) to run Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a [simple TextMate bundle](http://d43.me/blog/1538/run-python-ruby-php-bash-scripts-in-terminal-app-without-stealing-focus-from-textmate/) to run Python, Ruby, PHP, Bash scripts without stealing focus from TextMate and [released it on GitHub](https://github.com/EugeneDae/Run-in-Terminal-Bundle) under the MIT license.